# Screen reader support for vaadin 7.1

Tags: vaadin, accessibility, vaadin7, screen-readers

I am developing an application in vaadin and now needs screen reader for blind people. When I go to our application login page there are text fields like:

```
TextField tf = new TextField("Email");
TextField tf = new TextField("Password");
```

When I run application and embedded screen reader plugin of Chrome, and control goes over TextFields instead of saying Email it says textfield. How to make these text fields screen reader compatible?

I am using vaadin 7.1.

Comment: As I recall, Vaadin 8 & 10 have much improved accessibility features over 7, including support for screen readers. Read the Release Notes for details.

Comment: @Basil- Thanks for the help

Comment: Here is a Vaadin Ltd blog post from five years ago with accessibility tips that may help you. https://vaadin.com/blog/accessibility-with-wai-aria. And here is a closed Issue ticket for ARIA support that may be of interest: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues/34  And a quick demo of a screen reader with Vaadin 10: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5cdN0IsUPFg